# How can I keep a single instance of react-google-maps map while navigating other pages?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I have a loading screen that waits for the 'on tiles loaded' event to be triggered from the map. When I navigate using react-router, and navigate back, it completely re-creates the map again and the loading screen is required.

I don't want to have to load the map multiple times within the application lifecycle. Is it possible to just load it once and keep it somewhere? I understand react destroys objects that are not in the tree, but I wondered if I could hold a copy somewhere to be persistently used?

Comment: I don't know your code, but maybe shouldComponentUpdate resolve your problem: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: That wouldn't help me. When you navigate using react router, away from a page with a google map on it, I want to preserve that map, so when I navigate back, I can use the same instance.

Comment: Have you found any solution @MatthewHaworth ?